# i am getting type error in multiple inheritance in python opp

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import  random


class Coin:
    def flip(self):
        #toss=int(input('how many times you want to tosses the coin?: '))
        for i in range(self):
            rand=random.randint(-1,1)
            if rand==1:
                return rand
                #print("head")
            else:
                return rand
                #print('tail')
    print(flip(4))

class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        #x=int(input("inter number"))
        for x in range(self):
            points=random.randint(1,6)
            return points
    print(roll(5))

class Player(Coin,Dice):
    def rolls(self):
        # x=int(input("inter number"))
        for x in range(self):
            points = random.randint(1, 6)
            return points

    print(rolls(5))


obj=Player()
obj.flip()
obj.roll()
```

after running the code I get type error as TypeError: 'Player' object cannot be interpreted as an integer "
I want to make a program that will inherit Coin and Dice classes and in player class, I will give some condition like if flip=head then it will move forward and update the position from the initial position.

Comment: I know this is not your question, but I don't think it makes sense to use inheritance here. A player is not a type of coin. Instead they might *have* a coin, so you should use composition (`self.coin = Coin()`) instead of inheritance. If course, that doesn't apply if you're just playing around to see how things work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this line `for x in range(self):`? The [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function expects an integer (or multiple integers) as an argument, but instead you are passing the instance of the class itself (through the `self` parameter) causing the `TypeError` you are encountering

Based on your commented-out `input` calls, I'm guessing you mean to input a number and pass that number to the `range` function for your for loop instead:

```
class Coin:
    def flip(self):
        toss=int(input('how many times you want to tosses the coin?: '))
        for i in range(toss):
            rand=random.randint(-1,1)
            if rand==1:
                return rand
                #print("head")
            else:
                return rand
                #print('tail')
    print(flip(4))

class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        x=int(input("Enter number"))
        for i in range(x):
            points=random.randint(1,6)
            return points
    print(roll(5))

class Player(Coin,Dice):
    def rolls(self):
        x=int(input("Enter number"))
        for i in range(x):
            points = random.randint(1, 6)
            return points

    print(rolls(5))
```

You can (and should) read more about classes in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), but I think you may be misunderstanding how to use `self` in Python. Though this argument can technically be named anything, the `self` (by naming convention) argument in a class instance method refers to the instance of the class itself. So in your case, when you do `obj.flip()`, `self` will refer to the instance of the `Player` class which you instantiated (in other words, `obj`). So then trying to pass in this parameter to the `range` function, will cause the `TypeError: 'Player' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Coin:
    def flip(self):
        toss=int(input('how many times you want to tosses the coin?: '))
        for i in range(toss):
            rand=random.randint(-1,1)
            if rand==1:
                return rand
                #print("head")
            else:
                return rand
                #print('tail')
    print(flip(4))

class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        x=int(input("Enter number"))
        for i in range(x):
            points=random.randint(1,6)
            return points
    print(roll(5))

class Player(Coin,Dice):
    def rolls(self):
        x=int(input("Enter number"))
        for i in range(x):
            points = random.randint(1, 6)
            return points

    print(rolls(5))
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem.